# Show that If $|G|=p^2$ and $H\leq G$ with $|H|=p$, for $p$ any prime, then $H$ is normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $|G|=p^2$ and $H\leq G$ with $|H|=p$, for $p$ any prime, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

I am sort of stuck with this proof and I would appreciate a hint (not a full solution, please!). Preferably, please don't make use of the general case for the smallest prime dividing $|G|$.

Thanks!

Comment: @Brian I know. What I meant is that if you make use of a homomorphism, it should be an isomorphism. Maybe I should rephrase that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g\in G\setminus H$. Then $g$ has order either $p$ or $p^2$. For the first case we have $\langle g\rangle\cap H=1$. In the latter case $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: What does the first case show?

Comment: @Brian, then $G=\langle g,H\rangle$ and every element in $G$ has order $p$, and hence $G$ is elementary abelian.

Answer (score 1):

You know what $G$ is, either $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ (go ahead and prove this). Both are abelian. Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal (since everything commutes).

Answer (score 0):

Let $G/H=\{x_0H,...,x_{p-1}H \}$ (with $x_0=1$) and let $G$ act on $G/H$ by left-multiplication, that is $\phi : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} G & \to & \text{Bij}(G/H) \\ g & \mapsto & \varphi_g \end{array} \right.$ where $\varphi_g : x_iH \mapsto gx_iH$. Show that $\text{ker}(\phi)=H$.

Comment: How do I show $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: $\phi(gh)(x_iH)=ghx_iH=\varphi_g(hx_iH)= \varphi_g(\varphi_h(x_iH))$, so $\phi(gh)= \varphi_g \circ \varphi_h= \phi(g) \circ \phi(h)$.

Comment: I see. I asked because I thought we needed $G/H$ to be a group, but we don't.

Comment: Is there any other homomorphism that would work?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prove that $G$ is abelian.  **Hint** :Use the class equation to deduce that the center of $G$ is nontrivial.  Then suppose $a \notin Z(G)$. Derive a contradiction by finding suitable bound for $|C(a)|$, where $C(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$.  The full solution is given below.

> **Nontrival center**: The class equation gives $|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i=1}^n [G : C(a_i)]$, where $a_i \notin Z(G)$.  Then, $[G : C(a_i)] \ne 1$, so $p$ divides each index.  Since $p$ divides $G$, it follows that $p$ divides $Z(G).$

> **$G$ is abelian**: Suppose $a \in G$, and $a \notin Z(G)$.  Since the centralizer of $a$, $C(a)$ contains both $a$ and $Z(G)$ it is bigger than $Z(G)$.  However, $|C(a)|$ must be smaller than $|G| = p^2$ since $a$ does not commute with every element.  Hence, $|Z(G)| < |C(a)| < p^2$, a contradiction since $|Z(G)|$ is either $p$ or $p^2$.

Comment: I think your second argument is making things too complicated: we need only that the center is non-trivial to conclude that $G$ must be abelian. In effect, if the center has order $p$, then the quotient of $G$ by the center has order $p$, hence cyclic. But if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is itself abelian, a contradiction, thus the quotient can never be cyclic, that is to say, the center is the whole group and $G$ is abelian. Regards.

Comment: @awllower That would work, but I don't believe my argument is any more complicated than justifying the claim: $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian.

Comment: OK. Just saying. :D

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{core}_G(H)$ must be trivial if it is proper in $H$.  Thus if $G$ is nonabelian, then $G$ (a group of order $p^2$) injects into $\operatorname{Sym}(G\backslash H)$ (a group of order $p!$), which is impossible.